# Errors occured when switching from Uno to Nano Every

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

I wrote a code that worked perfectly on an Uno. I switched everything out to a Nano Every, and now I'm getting the following errors:

```
In file included from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src\LiquidCrystal.cpp:1:0:

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src\LiquidCrystal.h:45:36: error: expected class-name before '{' token
 class LiquidCrystal : public Print {
                                    ^
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src\LiquidCrystal.h:86:9: error: 'Print' has not been declared
   using Print::write;
         ^~~~~

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Nano Every.
```

I'm new to programming (this is the first thing I've done that wasn't from a tutorial), so I don't understand what any of the above means.

In the Tools dropdown, I have

Board: Arduino Nano Every

Registers Emulation: None (ATMEGA4809)

Programmer: Onboard Atmel mEDBG (Uno Wifi Rev2)

Here's the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Charging");
  delay(750);
  lcd.print(".");
  delay(750);
  lcd.print(".");
  delay(750);
  lcd.print(".");
  delay(750);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Charged");
}

void loop() {
  const int buzzerPin = 6;
  const int switchPin = 13;
  const int buttonPin = 7;
  const int ledPin = 9;
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  int switchState = digitalRead(switchPin);
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Mode: ");
  if (switchState == LOW) {
    lcd.print("Stun");
  } else {
    lcd.print("Kill");
  }
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    const int buzzerMax = 2000;
    const int time = 3;
    int buzzerTone;
    int totalReps = 50;
    int reps = 10;
    while (reps < totalReps) {
      buzzerTone = ((totalReps - reps) * 2 * (buzzerMax / totalReps));
      tone(buzzerPin, buzzerTone);
      analogWrite(ledPin, (255 / reps));
      delay(time);
      reps++;
      delay(time);
      if (reps == totalReps) {
        noTone(buzzerPin);
        analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
      }
    }
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Charging");
    delay(333);
    lcd.print(".");
    delay(333);
    lcd.print(".");
    delay(333);
    lcd.print(".");
    delay(333);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Charged");
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the Windows Store version of the IDE. That's known to be faulty in so many ways. Download the newest version from the Arduino website and update all the cores to the latest version.

Comment: it is a know issue with a workaround https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/10025